# How to send multiple model from a classbased view in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I made a booklist where cover image can be uploaded inside Booklist class. For more image I added another class called Bookcover. Now in Views.py how can I send both Booklist and Bookcover's by using BookListView

models.py file is below

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone



class Booklist(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    cover = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, default='default-book.jpg')
    description = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3, max_digits=100)

    def __str__(self):
    return self.title


class Bookcover(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Booklist, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    covers = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post.title
```

here is views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Booklist, Bookcover




def home(request):
    return render(request, template_name='home/index.html')

class BookListView(ListView):
    model = Booklist
    template_name = 'home/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'books'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make a `ForeignKey`, Django automatically will generate a relation in reverse to access - in this case - the related `BookCover`s for a specific `Book`. Since you did not specify the [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), the name of this relation is `modelname_set`, so in this case, `bookcover_set`.

In the template you can access the book covers of a book with:

```
{% for book in books %}
    {{ book.title }}
    {% for cover in book.bookcover_set.all %}
        <img src="{{ cover.covers.url }}">
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This will result in an *N+1* problem however. You can avoid that by using [**`.prefetch_related(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related):

```
class BookListView(ListView):
    queryset = Booklist.objects.prefetch_related('bookcover_set')
    template_name = 'home/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'books'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
```